# Send a String using Java Servlet over HTTP request

Tags: java, servlets

Hi I am trying to implement a server that takes in a string, then generates and returns another string to the client side, but it's not working well.

Here is what I tried:
Server:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ....
    String str = "something";

    // Return the queueId.
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(str);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

Client:

```
    String URL = "http://localhost:8080/"
    String serverURL = URL + "servlet?param=" + someParam;
    final URL url = new URL(serverURL)
    final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

But somehow br.readLine() is returning null. Which side is wrong in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `final URL url = new URL(serverURL + str); // I think... what is URL and serverURL`?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch   That was a typo occurred when I type this question, fixed that. I think that's not the bug in this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client should change as following. Since you are using a `doPOST` not `doGet`

```
String URL = "http://localhost:8080/"
String serverURL = URL + "servlet?param=" + someParam;
final URL url = new URL(serverURL)
final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

Your code as it is might be calling `doGet`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Should I use get or post in this case? or I should use both?

Comment: It is upto you based on the business logic you have. POST is usually for data modification and GET is usually for data retrieval